# The camera doesn't work with YOLO8, how do I fix it?

Tags: python

I am currently using Python 4 on VSCODE.  I have connected the  camera to the OpenCV and when I test the camera with   works, but when I want to use it locally with yolov8 for object detection and test it with models it throws an error. This is the code:

This is the error:

```
$ yolo task=detect mode=predict model=yolov8n.pt source=0 show=True
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.188  Python-3.11.5 torch-2.0.1+cpu CPU (AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core Processor)
YOLOv8n summary (fused): 168 layers, 3151904 parameters, 0 gradients

[ WARN:0@3.890] global cap_msmf.cpp:471 `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:0@3.892] global cap_msmf.cpp:483 `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:1@3.895] global cap_msmf.cpp:1759 CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147024809
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\yolo.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\cfg\__init__.py", line 445, in entrypoint
    getattr(model, mode)(**overrides)  # default args from model
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 224, in predict
    return self.predictor.predict_cli(source=source) if is_cli else self.predictor(source=source, stream=stream)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py", line 199, in predict_cli
    for _ in gen:  # running CLI inference without accumulating any outputs (do not modify)
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 35, in generator_context
    response = gen.send(None)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py", line 229, in stream_inference
    self.setup_source(source if source is not None else self.args.source)
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py", line 207, in setup_source
    self.dataset = load_inference_source(source=source,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\build.py", line 160, in load_inference_source
    dataset = LoadStreams(source, imgsz=imgsz, vid_stride=vid_stride, buffer=buffer)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Moslek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\loaders.py", line 69, in __init__
    raise ConnectionError(f'{st}Failed to read images from {s}')
ConnectionError: 1/1: 0... Failed to read images from 0
```

Can someone help me?

I used the virtual environment, I used the Bash terminal and the Python terminal itself.